# $\sin ^{-1}(\cos (40 {}^{\circ}))=50 {}^{\circ}$

Tags: calculus

I know this is very basic but I am struggling with understanding this?

$$\sin ^{-1}(\cos (40 {}^{\circ}))=50 {}^{\circ}$$

The step is this but I do not understand where what laws are used to get 90 degrees?
$$90 {}^{\circ}-\cos ^{-1}(\cos (40 {}^{\circ}))$$

Comment: Think of the names. COsine is the sine of the COmplement of the angle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\sin^{-1}(\cos(40°))=\sin^{-1}(\sin(90°-40°))=50°.$$

Comment: Relevant point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Answer (score 2):

The key point here is that $$\sin (90^{\circ}-x)=\cos x$$ which can be easily seen from the definitions on a right angled triangle. Your equation then follows by taking inverse sine of both sides.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\cos 40^\circ=\sin50^\circ \text{ because }40^\circ+50^\circ=\text{a right angle}.
$$

$$
\sin=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}\text{ and }\cos=\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}
$$
but the side that is **opposite** the $40^\circ$ angle is **adjacent** to the $50^\circ$ angle and vice-versa.